# InstallShield 2010, can't find how to make a file permanent (InstallScript MSI Project)

Tags: installshield

Where is this option? It should be on Files and Folders properties of a file...but...NO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the properties of the component containing the file, rather than the file itself.

Comment: Thanx, found it. But again, this cant select a single file inside this folder (component). Is there a way doing this?

Comment: Nope; if you need it to be one file and not the others, then you need to separate that file into its own component.